# Logstash Input cloudwatch plugin not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-cloudwatch

Getting the following exception when trying to pull logs from aws cloudwatch. Please let me know how to get the plugin working.

logstash version :5.1.1
Cloudwatch Input plugin version :2.0.0

10:51:06.452 [[main]"AWS/Logs", metrics=>["IncomingLogEvents"], filters=>{"LogGroupName"=>"test"},  id=>"5d5114c61b58d374e42e44ca04d64215282cf5c1-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=>"plain_be95e7fb-ed07-4d9c-a765-1a1308e51254", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, region=>"us-east-1", use_ssl=>true, statistics=>["SampleCount", "Average", "Minimum", "Maximum", "Sum"], interval=>900, period=>300, combined=>false>
  Error: No metrics to query
  Exception: RuntimeError

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on your local machine or on AWS?

**Local machine:**

---

Make sure you set the AWS credentials in the logstash conf file like this or point to your local aws credentials YAML file using the [aws_credentials](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-cloudwatch.html#plugins-inputs-cloudwatch-aws_credentials_file) property of the plugin

```
input {
    cloudwatch {
    namespace => "AWS/Logs"
    metrics => [ "IncomingBytes", "IncomingLogEvents"]
    filters => { "LogGroupName" => "/aws/lambda/your_lambda_name" }
    region => "us-east-1"
    access_key_id => "Insert access key ID"
    secret_access_key => "Insert secret access key"
    session_token => "Insert session token"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Note:** If you are using temporary AWS credentials make sure they are valid and have not expired.

**EC2**

---

Ensure that the IAM Instance Profile of the EC2 instance has access to cloud watch logs.

Reference - [Logstash Cloudwatch Input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-cloudwatch.html#plugins-inputs-cloudwatch-access_key_id)